# Unity2D (c#) - fall over edge like stone

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am make 2D platforming game in Unity and I have a problem: If my player goes over an edge the player falls along an arc trajectory. I want to make the player fall over the edge like a stone? Unable to alter the value of gravity.[image]

Comment: It will be better if u explain what a falling like a stone means ?

Comment: Do u wanna say not rotating just being still while falling ?

Comment: When player walking over edge, I want : player fall like stone (absolute vertically)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using 2D Physics with Rigidbody2D and Collider2D, you could, in your player script, set the horizontal velocity to 0 if the player is not grounded. To check if he is grounded, take a look at `Physics2D.CircleCast()`.

So you could add something like this to your script:

```
Rigidbody2D rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
if (isGrounded == false)
    rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(0, rb2d.velocity.x);
```

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"? Be sure that you only add force to your player from the input, if `isGrounded = true`.

Comment: @Adam This isn't a code writing site. I provided you with some useful information that you can use. One last tip i can give you is to take a look at `Physics2D.LineCast` and check down if a floor exists.